# Calculating difference between dates over month border with MomentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i want to show data from a certain day and display the correct date

structure is something like

```
daysago = [
{//...}, // today
{//...}, // yesterday
{//...}, // 2 days ago
{//...}, // 3 days ago
]
```

so if i want to get data from yesterday, i can just read `daysAgo[1]`

all is fine, except the date part.

today (3. feb), date from one day ago shows `33. February`.
i guess the problem is with moment.js having trouble with....something? (because it started at 1.feb)

```
getSingleDayStats = function(req, res, id, level, day) {

  var daysAgoStart = moment().subtract(day, 'days').startOf('day');
  var daysAgoEnd = moment(daysAgoStart).add(1, 'days');

  var dateString = moment(daysAgoStart).format('DDD. MMM YYYY'); // this ends up wrong
}
```

why is it wrong?
i don't even see a problem

`moment()` should return the current date.
i subtract 1 day and make it the string.

what's wrong here?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DDD` in moment, it's day of the year. To display date of the month you should do `DD`

```
var dateString = moment(daysAgoStart).format('DD. MMM YYYY');
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: oh god and i was just wondering why i used three letters :D thanks